# Bug in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a wave like effect in this program.
Here is the code.

```
var l = 74, t = 12; var k = 75, m = 14;
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i += 3) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var x = i + j;
        $(".s" + x).css({
            "left": l + "px",
            "top": t + "px"
        });
        l -= 50;
        t += 50;
    }
    k += 50;
    m += 50;
    l = k;
    t = m;
}
var c = 1, d;
function wave() {
    m = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        d = i;
        for (j = 1; j <= d; j++) {
            $(".s" + c).addClass("active");
            $(".s" + c).css({
                "animation-delay": c / 5 + "s"
            });
            alert(c);
            if (c != 1) {
                c += 2;
            }
        }
        m++;
        c = m;
    }
}
wave();
```

It uses jquery.
When i enable the alert in the code it animates in the order 1,2,4,3,5,7
But when i disable it the order is 1,2,3,4,5,7

I cant understand what is wrong.can anyone suggest what is the bug and how can we counter it.

Complete code 
    https://codepen.io/megatroncoder/pen/oxrPRg

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I can't read "phlarge". Please indent the code and give your variables meaningful names. If this is minified code, please provide the original source.

Comment: And post a [mcve] **in your question**

Comment: Proper indentation goes a long way to code readability and being understood by others.  If you are asking others to help, you want them be able to read your code and understand it.  Please help us, help you by making your code more readable.

Comment: "*can anyone suggest what is the bug*" There is no *bug*. The code is working as expected, per how you wrote it. But I can't even look at that garble. Please format it.

Comment: Ok i will indent the code and post it soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert` pauses execution of code until its window is closed.

If you put `console.log(c, c / 5);` instead of alert, you will see that `c` values are as expected, but your calculation of `animation-delay` is incorrect.

When `alert` pauses execution of loop, it seems that animation works as you wanted, but that is only because animations for next items were not started yet (they did not get `active` class).

When nothing pauses the loop, animations are started at the same time (in the same, correct order), but because of incorrect delays, they seem like they're running in wrong order.